# How do I sign a letter of recommendation, if I've left academia?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I recently left academia. A former student of mine asked for a letter of recommendation for graduate school applications. I've typically seen references sign with their title, to provide context. Should I sign mine as follows?

> My Name
> Former Thisorthat Postdoctoral Fellow
> Former Institution Name

Comment: You should provide the context in the first paragraph of your letter.

Comment: I think your example is good but you should make sure it is clear that Institution Name is the name where you have been, not where you are now.

Comment: I use the electronic letterhead of my former institution and place "(retired)" after my title in the signature area.  I've recommended students to advanced programs at that very same institution, including in my own department.  No one has complained.

Comment: @BobBrown Perhaps there is a difference between doing that as a retired faculty member- one who spend a long career- and a person who was a postdoc for a couple years.

Comment: @Damila  Yes.  That's why my answer below is different.  The comment is t help someone in a position similar ro mine.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, write on personal letterhead.  As Alexander Woo has said, the first paragraph should be something like this: "I'm writing in support of the application of Bob Brown to your doctor of divinity program.  Bob was my student when I was a postdoctoral fellow at the Close Cover Before Striking University."  Then you go on to explain briefly your qualifications to make the recommendation and in more detail why Bob would make an excellent and successful DD student.

Answer (score 2):

Per helpful suggestions in comments on the question, from [@Alexander-Woo](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/34050/alexander-woo) and [@user111388](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/111388/user111388), I described the context within which I worked with the student, and then later left academia, in the first paragraph:

> It is with great enthusiasm that I recommend Student for Grad Program
> in Research Field, at Your University. Student was an outstanding
> contributor to the team that I led as a postdoc at My Former Institution.
> Although I have since left academic research to work in industry my
> research experience with Student demonstrates her excellent fit and preparation
> for a career in Research Field.

And amended my signature (also in the question statement), to clarify I meant my most recent academic institution, at which I worked with the student:

> Sincerely,
> My Name
> Former Thisorthat Postdoctoral Fellow
> My Former Institution